# Android Fragment Dispose causes crash (sometimes)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I have a an MvxDialogFragment (Mvvmcross) which when closed, sometimes causes a Fatal Error.

The class:

```
namespace Keiser.IPS.Screen.Droid.Views
{
    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Widget;
    using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext;
    using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Views;
    using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging.Fragments;
    using Keiser.IPS.Screen.Core.ViewModels;
    using System;

    public class SettingsView : MvxDialogFragment
    {
        protected Android.Views.View InflatedView;

        public bool IsOpen { get; protected set; }

        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
        {
            base.EnsureBindingContextSet(savedState);
            IsOpen = true;

            SettingsViewModel.SystemSettingsEvent += GoToSystemSettings;
            SettingsViewModel.OnUpdateEvent += DoingUpdate;

            InflatedView = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.SettingsView, null);
            CheckDemoSection();
            CheckLicenseSection();
            CheckUpdateSection();

            MvxSpinner languageSpinner = InflatedView.FindViewById<MvxSpinner>(Resource.Id.LanguageSpinner);
            languageSpinner.Focusable = true;
            languageSpinner.FocusableInTouchMode = true;

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity, Resource.Style.Theme_Dialog);
            alertDialogBuilder.SetTitle(SettingsViewModel.GetText("GeneralSettings"));
            alertDialogBuilder.SetView(InflatedView);
            alertDialogBuilder.SetNegativeButton(SettingsViewModel.GetText("Cancel"), delegate { Cancel(); });
            alertDialogBuilder.SetPositiveButton(SettingsViewModel.GetText("Save"), delegate { Save(); });
            return alertDialogBuilder.Create();
        }

        protected SettingsViewModel SettingsViewModel { get { return ViewModel as SettingsViewModel; } }

        protected void Save()
        {
            SettingsViewModel.SaveSettings();
            IsOpen = false;
        }

        protected void Cancel()
        {
            IsOpen = false;
        }

        public override void OnCancel(IDialogInterface dialog)
        {
            base.OnCancel(dialog);
            Cancel();
        }

        protected void CheckLicenseSection()
        {
            if (!SettingsViewModel.ShowLicenseSection)
                InflatedView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SettingsContainer).RemoveView(InflatedView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.LicenseContainer));
        }

        protected void CheckDemoSection()
        {
            if (!SettingsViewModel.ShowDemoSection)
                InflatedView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SettingsContainer).RemoveView(InflatedView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DemoModeLabel));
            else
                InflatedView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.DemoModeLabel).Text += ": " + SettingsViewModel.GetText("On");
        }

        protected void CheckUpdateSection()
        {
            if (!SettingsViewModel.SoftwareManagerService.SoftwareManager.UpdateAvailable)
                InflatedView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SettingsContainer).RemoveView(InflatedView.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.UpdateContainer));
        }

        protected void GoToSystemSettings(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            StartActivityForResult(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionSettings, null), 0);
        }

        protected void DoingUpdate(object s, EventArgs e)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity).SetMessage(SettingsViewModel.GetText("UpdatingMessage")).Show();
        }

    }
}
```

View being infalted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/SettingsContainer">
        <TextView
            local:MvxLang="Text Language"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Mvx.MvxSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Languages; SelectedItem Language"
            android:id="@+id/LanguageSpinner" />
        <TextView
            local:MvxLang="Text Theme"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Mvx.MvxSpinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Themes; SelectedItem Theme"
            android:id="@+id/ThemeSpinner" />
        <TextView
            local:MvxLang="Text Legend"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Switch
            local:MvxBind="Checked Legend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
            local:MvxLang="TextOn On; TextOff Off" />
        <TextView
            local:MvxLang="Text DemoMode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/DemoModeLabel" />
        <TextView
            local:MvxBind="Text SoftwareCode"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/CodeLabel" />
        <TextView
            local:MvxBind="Text SoftwareVersion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/VersionLabel" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/LicenseContainer">
            <TextView
                local:MvxLang="Text LicenseKey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/LicenseKeyLabel" />
            <EditText
                local:MvxBind="Text LicenseKey; TextColor LicenseKeyColor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/SystemSettingsContainer">
            <Button
                local:MvxLang="Text SystemSettings"
                local:MvxBind="Click GoToSystemSettings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/UpdateContainer">
            <Button
                local:MvxLang="Text Update"
                local:MvxBind="Click DoUpdateCommand; Enabled CanDoUpdate"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the stack trace:

```
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero.
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076): Parameter name: jobject
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Android.Views.View.SetOnClickListener (IOnClickListener l) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Android.Views.View+<>c__AnonStorey7.<>m__0 (IOnClickListener __v) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Java.Interop.EventHelper.RemoveEventHandler[IOnClickListener,IOnClickListenerImplementor] (System.WeakReference& implementor, System.Func`2 empty, System.Action`1 unsetListener, System.Action`1 remove) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Android.Views.View.remove_Click (System.EventHandler value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Target.MvxViewClickBinding.Dispose (Boolean isDisposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBinding.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.ClearTargetBinding () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.Dispose (Boolean isDisposing) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxBinding.Dispose () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContext.ClearAllViewBindings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContext.ClearAllBindings () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging.Fragments.MvxBindingFragmentAdapter.HandleDestroyViewCalled (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.CrossCore.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise (System.EventHandler eventHandler, System.Object sender) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Fragging.Fragments.EventSource.MvxEventSourceDialogFragment.OnDestroyView () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Keiser.IPS.Screen.Droid.Views.SettingsView.OnDestroyView () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment.n_OnDestroyView (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
02-12 07:14:52.504: E/mono-rt(21076):   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object:4bb261f4-79d8-4e2d-80ec-785ea7b637ce (intptr,intptr)
```

It appears to me that an event handler is being removed from by the `MvxViewClickBinding.Dispose` method and that at some point in that process, the object is disappearing?  There is a check at the `MvxViewClickBinding.  Dispose` method to check if the object being touched still exists, so that leads me to think that somewhere lower down in the Android stack it is disappearing.

I've been fighting this for weeks, so if you have a suggestion, please let me know!

---

### Edit 1

I've added the view which is being inflated during the `OnCreateDialog` method.

What I mean by sometimes is that 9 out of 10 times the dialog closes without issue, but occasionally it will cause the app to crash.  I have seen it crash using both of the on screen buttons, as well as using an off dialog click or back button.

Here's the trace from within VS 2013:

```
02-13 03:22:37.084 W/InputEventReceiver(11572): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
An unhandled exception occured.
```

I can cause it every time if I trigger a GC immediately after the `OnDestroy` or `OnClose` methods.

It looks like the `MvxViewClickBinding.Dispose` method is pretty straight forward, so I'm not certain that this is an Mvx error.  It seems like something in the Android V4 Support library.

Here is the trace.txt file from the device: https://gist.github.com/bayssmekanique/af33048a94350a819f13

Comment: where's the actual binding? I can't see it in the question currently. Is there a simple project that repros it anywhere? Is there any clue on what "sometimes" means - any pattern you've managed to spot?

Comment: @Stuart I've updated the question with some additional deatail, the view being inflated, and the trace line from VS.